# continuewith task is not executed

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I'm trying to chain execution of tasks in this example:

```
static List<Task> clsTaskList = new List<Task>();

private static void Tasks2()
{
    Task t1 = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Main task started.");
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        Console.WriteLine("Main task finished");
    });

    Task t2 = new Task(() =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task 2 started");
        Thread.Sleep(15000);
        Console.WriteLine("Task 2 finished");
    });

    clsTaskList.Add(t1);
    t1.Start();

    clsTaskList.Add(t2);

    Task prevTask = clsTaskList.Last(p => p.IsCompleted == false);
    prevTask.ContinueWith(t => t2.Start());
}
```

What I'm trying to do is bind a continue task to the last task that is in the collection. But in the example, only the first task is executed. 
When I examine the collection, the status of the first task is `RanToCompletion` but the second's status is `Created`. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`prevTask` *is* `t2` when I run it; what you have basically said is "when `t2` has finished, start `t2`" - so obviously that won't happen. Importantly, at the point when `Last` runs, **neither** task has finished - so it makes sense that the "last" of the tasks that hasn't finished is the last one in the list, `t2`.

Options:

- explicitly use `t1.ContinueWith`
- use something like `Task.WhenAny`